# WD My Passport Reformat

Tags: macos, backup, external-hard-drive

My WD has run out of space.  I have deleted all the files on it, but doing this did not free up space; it is still at capacity.  Thus, I was thinking reformatting the drive might purge all the old backups I no longer want and renew the 500 GB of space.

The current formatting is OS Extended for Mac and I use a 2008 Macbook Pro Aluminum.  Also, I cannot find a WD application anywhere on my computer.  So, my questions:

- To restore the 500 GB of space, is reformatting the correct approach?
- If so, what do I do to reformat?
- Should there be WD Passport software somewhere in my applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reformatting should work, although when you delete files you should be seeing space freed up.

My guess is that your files are sitting "in trash".  Have you deleted the files in your trash bin?

Comment: Yes, emptying the trash bin is what needed to be done.  Thank you!